# Sort by Each Price Magento 2 via \Zend_DB_expr

Tags: magento2, product-collection, sorting

I've had this working previously however seems to be causing me some difficulty now, basically i have a unit of sale attribute that I am using to get an each price from the sale price:

```
if ($currentOrder == 'each_price') {
    $subject->getCollection()->addAttributeToSelect('unit_of_sale', 'catalog_product_entity_varchar');
    if ($subject->getCurrentDirection() == 'desc') {    
        $subject->getCollection()->getSelect()->order(array(new \Zend_Db_Expr('(minimal_price / IFNULL(unit_of_sale,1)) DESC')));
    } elseif ($subject->getCurrentDirection() == 'asc') {   
        $subject->getCollection()->getSelect()->order(array(new \Zend_Db_Expr('(minimal_price / IFNULL(unit_of_sale,1)) ASC')));
    }
}
```

This creates the below query:

```
SELECT `e`.*, `price_index`.`price`, `price_index`.`tax_class_id`, `price_index`.`final_price`, IF(price_index.tier_price IS NOT NULL, LEAST(price_index.min_price, price_index.tier_price), price_index.min_price) AS `minimal_price`, `price_index`.`min_price`, `price_index`.`max_price`, `price_index`.`tier_price`, `at_unit_of_sale`.`value` AS `unit_of_sale` FROM `catalog_product_entity` AS `e` INNER JOIN `catalog_product_index_price` AS `price_index` ON price_index.entity_id = e.entity_id AND price_index.website_id = '2' AND price_index.customer_group_id = 0 INNER JOIN `catalog_product_entity_varchar` AS `at_unit_of_sale` ON (`at_unit_of_sale`.`entity_id` = `e`.`entity_id`) AND (`at_unit_of_sale`.`attribute_id` = '207') AND (`at_unit_of_sale`.`store_id` = 0) ORDER BY (minimal_price / IFNULL(unit_of_sale,1)) DESC
```

However then spits out another seperate query that seems to be for the current page like below:

```
SELECT `e`.*, `price_index`.`price`, `price_index`.`tax_class_id`, `price_index`.`final_price`, IF(price_index.tier_price IS NOT NULL, LEAST(price_index.min_price, price_index.tier_price), price_index.min_price) AS `minimal_price`, `price_index`.`min_price`, `price_index`.`max_price`, `price_index`.`tier_price`, `stock_status_index`.`stock_status` AS `is_salable` FROM `catalog_product_entity` AS `e` INNER JOIN `catalog_product_index_price` AS `price_index` ON price_index.entity_id = e.entity_id AND price_index.website_id = '2' AND price_index.customer_group_id = 0 INNER JOIN `cataloginventory_stock_status` AS `stock_status_index` ON e.entity_id = stock_status_index.product_id AND stock_status_index.website_id = 0 AND stock_status_index.stock_id = 1 WHERE (stock_status_index.stock_status = 1) AND (e.entity_id IN (634, 611, 610, 609, 608, 624, 622, 734, 620, 1606, 736, 606))
```

This however does not include the order by like the previous. The first query in SQL does seem to return the results in the correct order of each price but 6000 results when this is a 34 product category. The second just returns the page but without my ordering.

So am doing something wrong here. I have tried numberous versions of above code in different ways however nothing seems to work for me so was hoping someone could see my issue?

Comment: For me the SQL looks OK and if you have numeric values in `unit_of_sale` that should give you the correct sorting. Since that attribute is of type `varchar` there can also be non-numeric values (not NULL but strings!). And a division of a number by a string will give NULL in MySQL. I would suggest to run that SQL and look at the values of the sorting expression

Comment: Yeah i was concerned about that also but they are all populated with numbers. I will try that and see how it goes, thanks